# Lights in the Dungeon: Three by Three

Tags: visual, story, mazes

This is the first in a series [Lights in the Dungeon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A9000%20is%3AQuestion%20title%3A%22Lights%20in%20the%20Dungeon%22) puzzles.

<sub>It is intended to be easy to help work out unpredicted kinks for future puzzles that are built around the same story.</sub>

<sub>[-> next (2nd)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/lights-in-the-dungeon-four-by-four)</sub>

---

You have been captured by Lord Hooty McOwlface, a cruel tyrant that tightly controls his territory with an iron <strike>talon</strike> fist. The dungeon is cold and without comforts but you are only kept there for a single night before you are hauled before the demonic ruler.

"You are a very lucky human!" screeches the despot. "We are going to play some games. If you perform poorly, you shall be eaten! But, if you perform well, you shall get to play another game! Does that sound fair?"

"Well," you stammer as you try to look at anything except his terrible countenance, "I suppose that's better than being eaten right away, isn't it?"

"Of course it is!  My grand vizier shall inform you of the rules. Be careful not to damage your delicious flesh if you lose. I would be most displeased." 
A bright purple cat disengages itself from the Lord's grasp and leaps from the arm of the throne. It approaches you with a scroll held in it's teeth.

"Is this your grand vizier?" you ask, incredulity sneaking into your voice.

"Fakky Jim is a trusted and noble creature! He is far superior to humans. Also, he's magic. Why did you think he was purple?"

You accept the scroll and unroll it to reveal the following rules:

> 1. You will be placed in a dungeon in which there are many rooms. Each room has a single light in the middle. You must turn off every
>      light.
> 2. The lights are easily turned off by a short chain hanging from the fixture.
> 3. As soon as you exit a room, the floor will collapse to reveal the thousand-foot chasm below. You may not re-enter a room and, therefore,
>      must turn off each light by passing through each room exactly once.
> 4. The map below shows the current design of the dungeon with each room bordered by red and labeled with a alphabetic character.
> 5. You may rearrange the rooms however you like before you enter but you cannot change the overall dimensions of the dungeon. In this case, that means the dungeon must be three rooms wide and three rooms tall.
> 6. You cannot rotate or flip rooms. You may only translate them.
> 7. You may only enter the dungeon once and exit once. As soon as you exit the dungeon, any remaining floors will collapse.
> 8. If there are any rooms not visited and, therefore, any lights left on, you lose. If all lights are turned off when you exit the dungeon,
>      then you win.

**How can you rearrange the dungeon rooms so that you can win the game?**

<sub>There are probably multiple solutions. The first valid answer will be accepted.</sub>

[image: Maze 3x3]

---

For reference, here are the 16 possible rooms. (Note that this is all *possible* rooms. For this puzzle, you must use exactly the rooms shown in the map above.)

[image: A][image: B][image: C][image: D][image: E][image: F][image: G][image: H][image: I][image: J][image: K][image: L][image: M][image: N][image: O][image: P]

Comment: "You will be placed in a dungeon" - do you get to pick which room you start in? Can it be any of the rooms, or does it have to be one that you can enter from outside the 3x3 grid of rooms?

Comment: @RobWatts It is intended that you must enter from the outside. I'll be sure to clarify that in the next round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope I got this right:

> [image: Solution]

Looking forward to the next one!