# Lights in the Dungeon: Eighteen by Eleven

Tags: story, visual, mazes

This is the fourth in a series [Lights in the Dungeon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A9000%20is%3AQuestion%20title%3A%22Lights%20in%20the%20Dungeon%22) puzzles.

<sub>[previous (3rd) <--](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23113/lights-in-the-dungeon-five-by-five)|[--> next (5th)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23260/lights-in-the-dungeon-hooty-and-the-message)</sub>

---

The [five by five dungeon](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/23113/9000) was only a little harder than the previous ones. You're feeling pretty good about it and you're even up for a little taunting. "Alright, Hooty, where the six by six?" you ask as you approach the cloaked figure waiting for you at the exit.

"Six by six?" asks the Lord, feigning ignorance. "I'm afraid I don't know what you talking about. You see, Fakky Jim and I have been working on your next challenge while you were busy rearranging tiles and walking through the dungeon, flipping lights like a good little monkey. Your next challenge is... a bit more grand. If you succeed, I promise to tell you the *real* reason I've brought you here."

Intrigued, you walk over to Fakky Jim and receive a scroll with the rules. You can tell they've been re-written from scratch as they were getting a bit illegible with all the strikethroughs and revisions from the previous puzzles.

> 1. You will enter a dungeon in which you must visit every room and turn off the light in the middle, an easy operation to perform.
> 2. As soon as you exit a room, every door to that room slams shut and locks. You can not re-enter that room through any means.
> 3. The map below shows the current design of the dungeon with each room bordered by red and labeled with a alphabetic character.
> 4. You may rearrange the rooms however you like before you enter but you cannot change the perimeter of the dungeon. In this case, that means you must maintain the exact stairstep shape that is eighteen rooms tall and somewhere between seven and eleven rooms wide.
> 5. You cannot rotate or flip rooms. You may only translate them.
> 6. The dungeon must have exactly one entrance and one exit.
> 7. There must be ***exactly one*** possible path through the dungeon. Obviously, any path is reversible if you simply enter from the other end but that does not count as a separate possible path.

Surprised, you look up at Fakky Jim and ask, "What happened to the collapsing floors?" The Grand Vizier just stares at you. You're not sure what you expected from a cat, magic though it may be. You turn to Lord Hooty and repeat the question.

"Ah," he starts, a sorrowful look upon his face, "we changed that after losing the cleaning crew. It was a tragedy, really. They were only doing their job. At least they were tasty so that's a silver lining."

---

**How can you rearrange the dungeon rooms so that you can win the game?**

<sub>There are probably multiple solutions. The first valid answer will be accepted.</sub>

[image: Maze 54x7,8,9,10,11,11]

```
AAAAAAA
AABBBBB
CCCCCCC
DDDDDDEE
EFFFFFFF
FFFFFFFF
FFFFGGGGG
GHHHHMMMM
MMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMMM
MMMMMMMMNN
NNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNN
OOOOOOOPPPP
PPPPPPPPPPP
PPPPPPPPPPP
```

---

For reference, here are the 16 possible rooms. (Note that this is all *possible* rooms. For this puzzle, you must use exactly the rooms shown in the map above.)

[image: A][image: B][image: C][image: D][image: E][image: F][image: G][image: H][image: I][image: J][image: K][image: L][image: M][image: N][image: O][image: P]

Comment: Wow, this is quite the challenge! Can you enter/exit the dungeon via the rooms at the staircase line?

Comment: @PrisonMonkeys You can enter / exit the dungeon from any room that has an opening on the perimeter of the dungeon no matter where those rooms are. Per rule 6, though, there can only be 2 such rooms.

Comment: @user1717828 Oh, um, you're welcome?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I started from the bottom-right corner and tried to get rid of all the Ms and Ns first, so I came up with:

> [image: Solution image]

Or as text:

> `ACPPPBC`
>  `PAGPPMM`
>  `PBHBOMM`
>  `PAGHHMMP`
>  `PPPPOMMP`
>  `FGGEDMMP`
>  `FGNOPMMFC`
>  `PPPFPMMMM`
>  `FHBEPMMMM`
>  `FADFCMMMMP`
>  `FBCFFMMMMP`
>  `AEFDFMMMMP`
>  `FNNNDMMMANC`
>  `ANNNCMMFNGM`
>  `FNNNOMFPFOM`
>  `ANNNNOFNDPM`
>  `FNNNNNNNNOD`
>  `ANNNNNNNNNN`

Comment: +1 for including the plain text version. That made it much easier for me to check that all the same tiles were included. Bonus points: Your answer will appear in the next challenge.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit messy, but this would work.

> [image]

Comment: The G at the right on row 11 is not allowed, as it offers an extra exit/entrance. But you could swap it with the C on line 3 to fix that.

Comment: And I interpreted rule 7 as disallowing what's happening in rows 12-16 on columns 3-4, although that's for @EngineerToast to decide.

Comment: Hmm, good points. For the r12-16, c3-4 issue, half of those could be swapped out for M pieces used elsewhere. TBH, the puzzle itself isn't terribly tricky, but it takes forever assembling all of the pieces with a computer mouse, hahaha.

Comment: There, fixed it :D